# Magento 2 B2B feature of EE

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, b2b

I am currently using Magento 2.2 Community Edition. I want the feature of Enterprise Edition B2B.

So where can i purchase this feature. I don't want to buy Enterprise Edition i just want the extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have used B2B of Webkul in one of our Website:

This is very useful Plugin of B2B Market Place, Link : [Click here](https://store.webkul.com/Magento2-B2B-Marketplace.html)

Or if you want, you have some more option: [One](https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-b2b-extensions-package.html), [two](https://www.iwdagency.com/extensions/b2b-ecommerce-suite-m1-m2.html).

Customer Quotation Module - [Click Here](https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-quote-extension.html)

Negotiation Module - [Click Here](https://www.elsner.com/magento-extension/magento-2-price-negotiation/)

Comment: Well we don't have supplier. Here we are the supplier and there are customer (wholesale) who will send quotation to us. Negotiation feature is need

Comment: Yes there is an extension for Negotiation - https://www.elsner.com/magento-extension/magento-2-price-negotiation/

Comment: You have also module of customer quotation - https://landofcoder.com/magento-2-quote-extension.html